# Approach for Update trigger for audit trail when updating > 30 columns using table valued parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a asp.net web form with more than 30 input controls which I am inserting for the first time using table valued parameter.

After saving them, I need to put functionality where I can update them and need to create audit trail (what was changed from *oldvalue* to *newvalue*).

I am thinking to update the values using table valued parameter (this way I will be updating all the values, even the *value1* again to *value1*) ans use [COLUMNS_UPDATED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql) to achieve the audit.*

So suppose I have 10 columns and I changed only 2 of them and when updating in SQL I update all of them. Will COLUMNS_UPDATED recognize if only 2 of them were changed?

Local m/c has SQL server 2008, planning to put them on Azure sql database when deploying

Am I going in right direction ? Please let me know if there is better approach, I will find out more.

Comment: what sql-server version are you using?

Comment: for local m/c SQL server 2008, planning to put them on Azure sql database when deploying.

Comment: You could just have a master table that holds the latest row, and each time an updated is requested, you copy the row to a history table before saving the update. there should be a natural link between the rows so you can join the history to main.

Comment: I need to create audit trail only for the changed new values. If old and new are same then I do not want to create trail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I did to achieve the solution.

Now my history table will look like this.
[image]

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trProjectDetails ON dbo.tbl_proj_details FOR UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @bit int ,@field int ,  @char int, @fieldName varchar(200)
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar(1000); 
DECLARE @temp varchar(100)

    Select * into #inserted from inserted
    Select * into #deleted from deleted
    SELECT @field = 0
    WHILE @field < (select max(colid) from syscolumns where id = (select id from sysobjects where name = 'tbl_proj_details'))
    BEGIN
        select @field = @field + 1
        select @bit = (@field - 1 )% 8 + 1
        select @bit = power(2,@bit - 1)
        select @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1
        --select @char, @field, @bit ,substring(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1), substring(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit  
            -- debug code to check the bits that are tested.
        IF substring(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0
        BEGIN
            select --@field as col#, 
            @fieldName = name from syscolumns 
            where colid = @field 
            and id = (select id from sysobjects where name = 'tbl_proj_details')

            SET @sqlText = N'Insert into [dbo].tbl_proj_action_history 
                            select ins.proj_id, getdate(), SYSTEM_USER , ''' + @fieldName + ''', del.'+ @fieldName +', ins.' + @fieldName + ' 
                            from #inserted ins , #deleted del 
                            where ins.proj_id = del.proj_id';

            exec (@sqlText)  
        END
    END
    DROP table #inserted
    DROP table #deleted
GO
```